# Elementor form giving Red "X" error on submissions

Tags: elementor

I am using elementor forms on one of my website, but when i submit, it shows a red 'X' error with no details on frontend although the form details are successfully send on email and at backend of wordpress

Additional Plugin Used with Elementor is (Dynamic Content for elementor)

can anybody help me resolving this error
Form Url- https://guysanddolls.co.in/

Comment: to understand the issue you should retrieve your php error logs.

Comment: from where i can get the same you said?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the access to `/wp-admin` was restricted to certain IPs in the `.htaccess`. Removing the restriction made it work again.